What is a building with two floors called?
In American English, the first floor is the floor that is on the same level with ground, which is called ground floor in British English. And  British first floor is American second floor.
Given this, when one says "two-storey (two-story) house", how many floors does it have? In America, I suppose it naturally means a house with the first and second floor. In UK, does it have two floors or three floors?

A background to this question is that French seems to use the number consistently with  counting floor so that "maison à étage" (with single 'étage') means a house with two floors. I'm wondering if it is the same with British English or not.

We're getting a lot of questions about homes recently: 1. Is it natural to say that houses are "closer/lower to the ground"? and 2. What would you call the ground floor if you were in a country where it is the first floor? and 3. Is there a word that means both "house" and "apartment"?

4. Is this the difference between an efficiency apartment and a studio apartment? 5. What is the difference an entryway, entry, entrance hall, vestibule, foyer and mudroom? 6. What is this enclosed space that projects out of the house called?

Maybe someone should create a specific tag?

domicile .... except even in AmE, it can mean which country you're from.

Gah, one at a time, woulldddyaaa. You got a bunch of Brits answering AmE questions. And soon to be vice versa.

And we do use ground floor in American English, but not of the first floor in a two-stor(e)y house; we use of the street-level floor of tall buildings such as, say, a ten-storey department store, a high-rise apartment building, or a skyscraper.

I'm going to be asking  a few questions about British doghouses and British bordellos. Can we have a separate tag for each?

In both American and British English, a two-story (or two-storey) house has two floors. The difference lies in the naming convention of the floors themselves, not in the total count of the floors.
American English:
First Floor: The ground-level floor.
Second Floor: The floor above the ground level.
Two-Story House: A house with two floors, including the ground level and the floor above it.

British English:
Ground Floor: The ground-level floor.
First Floor: The floor above the ground level.
Two-Storey House: A house with two floors, including the ground level and the floor above it.

Note:  "I live on the second story/storey." and "I live on the second floor." is same.

American English: A grade-level floor would be a first floor walk-in. 99% of "first floors" are about half a flight of steps up, so that the garden level (the basement) can have some windows. Second Floor: is the floor above the first floor. Two story houses don't necessarily have a basement.

"A house with two floors, including the ground level and the floor above it." "A house with two floors, {which are the} ground level and the floor above it." - "including the ground level and the floor above it" : means you're counting the basement and the attic of a two story house, which is saying there is four 'floors'.

@Mazura  Not quite sure what you are trying to say, but typically neither a basement nor an attic would count as a "storey".

@Mazura That depends on where you are. In the South, very few buildings have basements due to the difficulty in keeping water out. In the Pacific Northwest, very few buildings have basements due to the high bedrock. I've lived in both places, and having any more than one or two steps up to the first floor is unusual, with most places having no steps up. Certainly not a whole half flight of stairs.

@Mazura If a residential house has a basement, a ground-level floor, an upstairs floor and an attic, that would still be a two-storey house, not a four-storey house. Conversely, a car park that has six levels beneath ground and one at ground level would be a seven-storey car park. To me at least, when describing how many storeys a building has, only those storeys that serve the purpose of the building are counted. If a building has a ground-level lobby, ten floors of offices above ground, and five levels of parking underground… I honestly don’t know how many storeys I’d say that building has.

In British English, you'd almost never refer to the ground and first floor of a two story house, you'd call them upstairs and downstairs. We only use ground, first, etc. for buildings with more stories than that.

No, it is not the same. The ground floor is counted as a storey in British English, so a two-storey house has a ground floor and a first floor.

In 99.9% of cases there is no special term used.  That's because having two floors is the default for "houses" in the UK.  Houses with a single floor are fairly common but special enough to get a special name "bungalow".  Houses with three or more floors are also exceptional, and would probably be some kind of "townhouse".
So there's no particular name for a house that has an upstairs and downstairs.  If you need to describe such a house you could use "two-story house" or "house with two floors".  You would not usually use "ground floor/first floor" for such a house, but just "downstairs/upstairs".
I'd note that the attic-space is not normally counted as a separate story, even if it is converted to a living space.

In the US, the term "ranch" sometimes serves the same purpose as "bungalow", meaning a one-story house (which can be confusing as the same word also refers to a property where livestock are raised).  Then there's the question of whether basements count as floors, and also there are cases of houses built on a slope so they appear to have one floor in the front and two in the back or vice-versa...

I've always wondered if "ranch" also comes from India.

Like the attic, a basement would also not be counted as a separate story, even when made into living space.  Also: At least in some regions "bungalow" implies very specific architectural features beyond building height (and those features may have further regional or historical variations). In Chicago, we even have a "Bungalow Belt" where the ca. 1920 version of this local vernacular architecture predominates.

And in the U.S., "bungalow" can also mean a house with a full first story and a partial second story, this reference sense 3.  Whereas "ranch" definitely means something with only one story (not counting any basement), and suggests a linear layout as well.

@Fattie FYI Rancho is an extremely common placename component all over the US southwest (Rancho Bernardo, Rancho Cucamonga, etc)

Cheers @JamesMoore and JamesK, I do know what a ranch (farm -like facillty) is and I've even lived in a Rancho X !  This: I've always wondered if "ranch" also comes from India. was an (apparently too subtle) joke, the word "bungalow" is an Indian ie Hindi loan word (as are a number of words in the UK, ie, from the historical period where we were trying to take over the subcontinent ...) {Basically from Bangalore or Bengal.}

BTW regarding "ranch" as in US usage -style house, I've always wondered how the connection came from "ranch" (or "rancho").

Oh, I googled the term and instantly found it, apparently from perhaps the 30s, real estate jargon would .. The house style was dubbed a Ranch, or Rambler, because of the wide-open-spaces appeal this new type of home nodded to, and the tenable connection to true cattle ranches, which were also horizontal in shape (albeit larger), with low-pitched roofs, and a similar connection to the outdoors.  (ironically modern day actual houses-of-a-ranch are 2 story usually, like in the movie The parent trap say)

PS I would have expected more folks on this site to pick up on a joke like that! * sniff *

Matlab counts arrays from one while Python counts from zero, but the length of any given array doesn't change. Citizens of the USA and citizens of the UK act the same with respect to counting stories and the total height of a construction.
The beauty of conventions is, everyone can have their own.


how many floors does it have

While the most common ways of naming the floors may differ among various varieties of English, the overwhelming majority of people have no difficulty agreeing on how to count floors in English. If you're confident you can count floors in one variety of English you'll get to the same total number in another major variety of English.
